# matplotlib and anaconda issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I uninstalled matplotlib, but now for *whatever* command I try to run on my terminal, matplotlib-related or not, I get the following message. How do I solve?

Error processing line 1 of /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib-2.2.2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 568, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Comment: how did you uninstall matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

If you already uninstalled matplotlib, you can safely remove the `.pth` file and the problem should go away.